# Java, method not applicable for arguments

Tags: java

I'm trying Java and got this code:

```
    package mysecondclass;

    public class MySecondClass {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
              mysecondclass("String", "String1", "String2");

          }

        //private static MySecondClass(final String string, final String string2, final String string3) }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        private static void mysecondclass(String string, String string2, String string3; }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        public MySecondClass(String object, String object1, String object2) {
               System.out.println(object);
               System.out.println(object1);
               System.out.println(object2);
             }
        }
```

Now is the problem that I get an error and I've no idea how to resolve.

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:     The method mysecondclass(String, String) in the type
> >     MySecondClass is not applicable for the arguments (String, String,
> >     String)
>
> at mysecondclass.MySecondClass.main(MySecondClass.java:5)

Comment: Check the code you posted here. This code has different problems. Not the problem you asked (in particular it doesn't compile because it has some problems on parenthesis)

Comment: Coding in an IDE like Eclipse would help you reduce compilation errors.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow - before you create your first post you should always do the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and most importantly : read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also : there are no "scripts" in Java. Java is a **programming language**, which is very different to a *scriptlanguage*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change method declaration to

```
private static void mysecondclass(String string, String string2, String string3){
System.out.println(string+" "+string2+" "+string3);
}
```

a circular bracket is missing in your code and also remove the semicolon after that.

Comment: Well, it worked somehow but it doesn't show up with any content now. Do I need use " for the print?

Comment: @Korkel because you dint have anything inside the method add a print statement inside it

Comment: I have? It's all new for me. :(

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 string1 cannot be resolved to a variable

 at mysecondclass.MySecondClass.mysecondclass(MySecondClass.java:14)
 at mysecondclass.MySecondClass.main(MySecondClass.java:5)

Comment: @Korkel that was my mistake try my code now updated my answer

Comment: It's working, now trying to figure out how to change texts, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change

private static void mysecondclass(String string, String string2, String string3; }

to

private static void mysecondclass(String string, String string2, String string3**)** }

parenthesis is missing...